# SpringBook + VueJS + SpringSecurity Cookie is not passed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, kotlin, spring-security

I'm creating a project using SpringBoot2 and VueJS. I'm using a custom JWT token for authorisation. When the user logs in I set a cookie in the response "AUTH_TOKEN=tokenValue". I expected that every call from VueJS (using `fetch`) would pass that cookie to SpringBoot, but not all endpoints get the cookie.

When I test SpringBoot with RestTemplate and with Postman the cookie is passed just fine and the endpoint works. When I use the VueJS website, the cookie is only passed to endpoints that have "permitAll" in my SecurityConfig.

I have also verified that my VueJS is always sending the cookie (I used a php endpoint to test this and the cookie is always there). So something happens when I use the browser and not all endpoints have the cookie. Here is my Config and how I use it:

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
open class SecurityConfig(private val jwtTokenProvider :JwtTokenProvider) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {


    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        //@formatter:off
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/thisEndpointDoesGetTheCookie").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() //Anything else does not
                .and()
                .apply(JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
        //@formatter:on
    }

}
```

When I set another endpoint with `permitAll` then that endpoint starts getting the token too (in my jwtConfigurer/provider)

The call is done using `fetch` and VueJS

Here is my logout example (same as any other endpoint)

```
    logout() {
      fetch('http://localhost:8100/auth/logout', {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            ,credentials: 'include', //Yes I'm including the credentials
            body: ""
          }).then(res => {
            console.log("Logout was successful");
          }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error.message);
              console.log("Logout failed");
          });
    },
```

This is how I set the cookie when the user logs in. I can see it in the browser

```
    // create a cookie
    val cookie = Cookie("AUTH_TOKEN", signedInUser.token)

    // expires in 30 days
    cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    // optional properties
    cookie.secure = authTokenCookieSecure //false for localhost
    cookie.isHttpOnly = true
    cookie.path = "/"
    // add cookie to response
    response.addCookie(cookie)
```

When I make the call using TestRestTemplate (from my tests) or when I'm using 
postman the endpoints behave as expected.

```
val headers = HttpHeaders()
headers["Cookie"] = "AUTH_TOKEN=$jwtToken"
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Problem occurs because you have to configure CORS in Spring Security.
For custom headers you have to set your header name in Access-Control-Expose-Headers.

Example solution code:

```
@Bean
fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
    val configuration = CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()
    configuration.allowedOrigins = listOf("*")
    configuration.allowedMethods = HttpMethod.values().map { it.name }
    configuration.allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
    configuration.exposedHeaders = listOf("AUTH_TOKEN")
    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
    return source
}
```

This CORS configuration allows any domain to access your header. It's good solution for DEV environment. For PROD you should specify origin instead of providing *.

Links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are almost there. But this was not enough to fix it. The problem is that "fetch" and "axios" do a "pre-flight" request using "OPTIONS" request type and it does not send the cookie. If that call is successful then they do the full request. So I had to allow all "OPTIONS" calls to not be authenticated. I will post a full solution later.

```
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll() //This it to allow PreFlight checks from the browsers
```